# How to show that for a monotone increasing function over a closed interval $[a,b]$, $f(a)$ + the sum of all jumps is less than or equal to $f(b)$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
I'm wondering about the (why?) comment - and am failing to prove it rigorously. The $c$'s are the points of discontinuity.

Comment: What is the relation between $c$ and $I$ to $a$ and $b$?

Comment: sorry c are all points of discontinuitiy, and j(c) is the jump

Answer (score 1):

First, we note that if $f$ is monotonically increasing, then $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ exist at every point $x$ (For a proof, see Baby Rudin Theorem 4.29). More precisely,
$$\sup_{t<x}f(t)=f(x-)\le f(x)\le f(x+)=\inf_{t>x}f(t)$$
and $f(x+)\le f(y-)$ for $x<y$.
Therefore, if $a$ and $b$ aren't jumps, we have
\begin{align}
f(a)&\le f(a)+j_f(x_1)+j_f(x_2)+\dots+j_f(x_n)\\
&=f(a)+(f(x_1+)-f(x_1-))+(f(x_2+)-f(x_2-))+\dots+(f(x_n+)-f(x_n-))+(f(b)-f(b))\\
&=(f(a)-f(x_1-))+(f(x_1+)-f(x_2-))+(f(x_2+)-f(x_3-))+\dots+(f(x_{n-1}+)-f(x_n-))+(f(x_n+)-f(b))+f(b)\\
&\le 0+0+\dots+0+f(b)
\end{align}
Also remember that a monotonic function can only have countably many discontinuities, all of which are jumps. So, letting $n\to\infty$ it is also true that $$f(a)\le f(a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty j_f(x_n)\le f(b).$$

Note: if $a$ is the jump $x_1$, then we let $j_f(x_1)=f(a+)-f(a)$, if $b$ is the jump $x_n$, then we let $j_f(x_n)=f(b)-f(b-)$, and the proof can go on as usual.

Comment: Is this proof over an open interval though? Because it seems the definitions of jumps you're using are for points c which are not endpoints?

Comment: If $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$ then it is also monotonic on $(a,b)$. If $x$ is an endpoint then one of the two limits doesn't exist, but the proof is the same.